# stepAIC forward function in R has a long run time

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am using the stepAIC function in R to run a stepwise regression on a dataset with 28 predictor variables. The backwards method is working perfectly, however the forward method has been running for the past half an hour with no output whatsoever this far. I believe it is to do with how I'm defining the scope attribute. Without the scope it runs instantaneously however only one step is run and no changes are made to the initial model.

```
Bstep.NNN.top<-step(lm(Response~X1+X2+X3+X4+.....+X28,data=df),
scope=list(upper=Response~X1*X2*X3*.....*X28,lower=Response~1),direction=c("forward"))
```

Does anybody know of a method that is quicker to run? Or if there is a way to simplify the scope attribute to a point where the run time will decrease?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use stepwise regression. Use the lasso, via the [`glmnet`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=glmnet) package instead.

Comment: Lasso tends to give better models as it shrinks the coefficients making it harder for spurious relationships to enter the model. However, stepwise regression is fine if you know there are limited . Unsure why that is stalling out though.